# What is the better way to create navigation for 2 pages application?

Tags: navigation, mobile-application

I am working on wireframes for small application, which has 2 screens. One of them is primary, the other one is secondary. Now I am thinking of what is the best way to create navigation for this kind of application.

What would be your advices?

Comment: What is the nature of these screens? What's in them? Basically you have two nodes, with a single relationship between them - that's a very very loose navigation problem, because it seems there really aren't any options other than moving back and forth between these two nodes.

Comment: The first one is the main one. It allows you to compare the products. The second one is just a list of deals - products with discounts.

The first thing came into my mind is just to create two links at the top bar. On the left - menu icon, on the centre - two links to this screens.

Comment: It is still not clear. I guess you would have to add some sketches of what you are doing. What is the exact relation between these two screens? Inter-dependencies?

Comment: Navigation between two screen can be achieved in number of ways. Linear navigation, persitent navigation, link navigation and combination of these. Depends on nature of content.

Answer (score 1):

For a 2 page interaction you can use the tab approach, but make sure that selected tab is indicated better.

Since the pages are not linked then the tabs should work.